# mapView current location blue dot along with torch as in Maps app callout rotation issue

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I am implementing `showuserlocation=TRUE` property to show a blue dot on map.
Clicking on blue dot will produce a callout with title Current Location.

I am referring the Default Maps App on iPhone. I have applied the Headings to it so it rotates to show North same as Maps App.

But when my map rotates as with Heading, Current Location Callout also rotates.

I want it to stay at one place as in iPhone Map App.

Comment: What does "along with torch" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want callout to be vertical at all times

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{

for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations) 
    {
      NSLog(@"keep callout vertical");
      MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
     [annotationView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0)];
   }
}
```

Comment: HI,I tried this but this didnt work out.Please check if i miss anything.

Comment: @VikasOjha, I have updated code in answer. It is annotationView to which transformation should be applied and not annotation itself. See is this is working. Also make sure that NSLog is printing "keep callout vertical" to make sure code inside for loop is executing